# Pull Activerecord join table information through controller query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, activerecord, controller

I have a query that generated a list of product data; I am working to dig in a bit deeper and extract an attribute from a join table (ProductSelections). Both RFIDTag and Products have many of the Product Selections model (i.e. the schema table contains both an rfid_tag_id and a product_id). Since I'm working from the product list, I'm deriving my query from here:

```
#original query (works as needed):

@warehoused_products = Product.includes(:rfid_tags).joins(:rfid_tags).where("rfid_tags.location_type = 'Warehouse' AND rfid_tags.location_id = ?", params[:id]) 

#Attempt at getting product selection data:

@product_histories = @warehoused_products.joins("INNER JOIN product_selections ON :product_selections.product_id = products.id").includes(:product_selections)
```

This raises a fairly large postgreSQL error when I check it:

```
raise @product_histories.inspect:

PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near ":" LINE 1: ...eted_at" IS NULL INNER JOIN product_selections ON :product_s...
```

On adjusting the query:

```
raise @warehoused_products.includes(:product_selections).joins(:product_selections).where("product_selections.product_id = ?", params[:product_id]).first.inspect
```

I get a a `nil` result - error-free, and likely cleaner, but not quite there.

A Product Selection object looks like so, for reference:

```
#<ProductSelection id: 269, user_id: 2, listing_id: 11, product_id: 35, created_at: "2016-07-14 15:38:11", updated_at: "2016-08-08 21:10:13", rfid_tag_id: 575, part_id: nil, use_time: 2173274, account_id: 1, deleted_at: nil>
```

How can I resolve the query so that I can pull the associated table object?

Answer (score 0):

```
@warehoused_products = Product.includes(:rfid_tags).where("rfid_tags.location_type = ? AND rfid_tags.location_id = ?", 'Warehouse', params[:id]) 


@product_histories = @warehoused_products.includes("product_selections").where("product_selections.product_id = ?", params[:product_id]).first.inspect
```

Comment: That's the second thing I tried - I get `nil` from this (this version makes it back into an instance variable, but still the same)